# Artifcatory: Error when using artifactory docker bitbucket pipeline

Tags: artifactory

I am passing the following

```
      - pipe: JfrogDev/artifactory-docker:0.2.12
        variables:
          ARTIFACTORY_URL: "${JFROG_URL}"
          ARTIFACTORY_USER: "${JFROG_USER}"
          ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: "${JFROG_PASSWORD}"
          DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: "xxxx/web-interface:${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
          DOCKER_TARGET_REPO: "local-containers"
```

And I am getting back the following

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for jfrog-int-docker-open-docker.bintray.io/artifactory-docker:0.2.12
INFO: Starting pipe execution...
jfrog rt config --url=$JFROG_URL --user=$JFROG_USER --password=$JFROG_PASSWORD --interactive=false
[Error] Wrong number of arguments. You can read the documentation at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI
```

It can’t find anything wrong based on the documentation, it looks like the pipeline makes a cli call and that call is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue when trying to config the server without the mandatory server-id argument:
https://bitbucket.org/JfrogDev/artifactory-docker/src/3b32b5d01d31c07acadb2a0d29a240110f88d59d/pipe/pipe.sh#lines-65

Instead, you can use the new [jfrog-setup-cli](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=jfrog/jfrog-setup-cli) pipe. This pipe downloads and configures the JFrog CLI.

For example, in your case:

```
- pipe: jfrog/jfrog-setup-cli:1.0.0
- source ./jfrog-setup-cli.sh
- jfrog rt docker-push "xxxx/web-interface:${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}" local-containers
```

It requires to populate one secured environment variable prefixed by `JF_ARTIFACTORY_` (i.e. `JF_ARTIFACTORY_MYSERVER`) with a JFrog CLI server token. This token created locally in your machine using the `jfrog rt config export` command.

Read more about this pipe [here](https://bitbucket.org/jfrog/jfrog-setup-cli/src/master/README.md.).

Read more about the `jfrog rt config export` command [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Configuration).